# Show the following ring does not have nontrivial two sided nilpotent ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, galois-theory

Let $k$ be a field. $A/k $ is a finite dimensional algebra with no non-trivial nilpotent two sided ideals. If $G/ k$ is Galois, then is it true that the ring $A \otimes _k G$ does not have any non-trivial two sided nilpotent ideal?

Answer (score 2):

A finite-dimensional algebra over a field is semisimple if and only if it has no nontrivial nilpotent two sided ideals, so the statement follows from your previous question [Show the following ring is semisimple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192717/show-the-following-ring-is-semisimple/1192807).

Concerning the above statement about the connection between semisimplicity and nilpotent two-sided ideals:

A finite-dimensional algebra $A$ is semisimple if and only if its radical ideal $\text{rad}(A)$, the intersection of all maximal left ideals, is trivial (the vanishing of $\text{rad}(A)$ is equivalent to the existence of an injection $A\rightarrowtail M_1\oplus\ldots\oplus M_n$ for $M_i$ simple left $A$-modules, whch in turn is equivalent to the semisimplicity of $A$). Since $\text{rad}(A)$ is a two-sided, nilpotent ideal (nilpotency follows from Nakayama's Lemma), this proves "$\Leftarrow$". Conversely, suppose $A$ is semisimple and let $I\lhd A$ be a nontrivial two-sided ideal. By semisimplicity of $A$, there exists a complementary left ideal $J\lhd A$, that is, $A = I\oplus J$. Writing $1 = e_1 + e_2$ for $e_1\in I, e_2\in J$ then gives $e_1 = e_1\cdot 1 = e_1^2 + e_1 e_2$, so we get $e_1 e_2\in I\cap J=\{0\}$ and we get $e_1 = e_1^2$. Further, $e_1\neq 0$ since for $x\in I\setminus\{0\}$ we have $x = x\cdot 1 = x e_1 + x e_2$, so $x e_2 = 0$ and $0\neq x = x e_1$ by the same reasoning. Hence, any nontrivial two-sided ideal of $A$ contains a nontrivial idempotent, hence cannot be nilpotent.

Comment: Thank you. But can you see if there's a direct way to do this problem? I understand this one is equivalent to the previous one.

Comment: @user112564 There doesn't seem to be any good reason to handicap oneself by not applying the previous result. Any direct proof would largely repeat the work in that problem.

Comment: @user112564: I'm sorry, I don't know a more direct approach.